# Is the subset of f(x) in X the codomain?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

Let :⟶ and assume *A, B* ⊂ *X* and  *C, D* ⊂ *Y*.

Then, $f^{-1}(Y\setminus C)$ = $X \setminus f^{-1}(C)$

The left hand side is pretty obvious. Assume x $\in$ $f^{-1}(Y\setminus C)$, this means that $f(x) \in Y \setminus C$

For the right hand side, I tried the following. Assume $x \in X \setminus f^{-1}(C)$, therefore $f(x) \in f^{-1}(X) \setminus C$.

$f^{-1}(X)$={$x \in X| f(x) \in X$}

Now comes the part I'm not certain of. To prove the statement, $f^{-1}(X)$ needs to be equal to $Y$, because then the right-hand side would become $f(x) \in Y \setminus C$. However, I don't know whether that is the case and whether it's obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\in X\setminus f^{-1}(C)$, this means that $x\notin f^{-1}(C)$, so there is no $c\in C$ such that $f(x)=c$, or in other words, $f(x)\notin C$. Therefore, $f(x)\in Y\setminus C$.